# How to modify a workflow from rehosted workflow designer on runtime?

Tags: .net, runtime, workflow-foundation-4

I have the rehosted workflow designer, but I want to modify a workflow of an application at runtime. How I can accomplish that?

Fonts: [Rehosted Workflow Designer](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx)

If I have a process based on a workflow (I understand that running instance can not modify), but can new instances be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to modify a running instance? If so you can't.

Using the code from my blog post you can change the XAML workflow definition. After that you can load the new definition using the ActivityXamlServices.Load() and execute it as is shown at the bottom of the blog post.